# What does "gemlely" mean?

Tags: vocabulario

My eight year old, who is more or less bilingual (whereas I don't speak Spanish), made me a birthday card. In it, among more understandable things, he wrote

> Tu eres un papa gemlely feliz.

Obviously, he messed up. "Gemlely"? But I don't know enough Spanish to figure out what he meant.  Any ideas, people?

I should add that he didn't know either.

Comment: If he doesn't know what he was saying, how can we know? It is neither English nor Spanish.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not a native speaker, but this doesn't look like a Spanish word to me.

Could it be that he misspelled the English word *genuinely*?

Answer (score 4):

I'm Spanish, and Spanish speaker. And I have never heard or read this word.

Definitive and absolutely, **gemlely** isn't a Spanish word.

Answer (score 1):

THE SOLUTION
My son just figured out the answer.
He was trying to write genial y feliz.
But got the y too close.
And thought that it was gemial.
And from there, mis-spelt as gemiel.
And with terrible handwriting, gemlel.
(The dot on the i looks like an extension of the long stroke, but if you look carefully, it is indeed an i.)
OK, so Glorfindel was closest, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Desde mi punto de vista su hijo ha mezclado varias ideas en Español e Inglés, y aunque la palabra existe en ambos idiomas, en Inglés su significado y utilización no son tan frecuentes como en Español. Así, cuando dice "gemlely", está diciendo "general", "generalmente" (generally), en un sentido amplio de "muy", "bastante", "grande", "mucho", y que desborda en esa mezcla de lenguas el propio contenido y concepto de la palabra, que en Inglés es "usually", (mostly, most), y que no posee totalmente la misma figura que en Español ya que a esa edad, ese "general", como algo grande que abarca gran cantidad de cosas y que nosotros interpretamos como muy, más, mucho....pueden confundirse.

Su hijo quiere decirle en sentido estricto: "Tú eres un papá muy feliz".

Comment: gemlely no existe en inglés.

Answer (score 0):

Same here: doesn't sound like any Spanish word that I know of.

If I had to make a guess, I'd say he may have tried to write "genial". If the "ml" could be "ni" miswritten. If he saw the plural of "genial" (geniales), he could have seen the 2nd "e" letter there. And if he then tried to make it an adverb, for the last "y", then he could have ended up writing "gemlely"... but I wouldn't take a bet on that. I think it's more likely something like @Glorfindel's answer, a genuinely misspelled word in another language.